# 3D vision with one camera / VSLAM with known position

Tags: navigation, mapping, camera, 3d-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to map an environment with a single camera which moved through the environment with a known trajectory. So that I create a 3D map. Several SLAM systems can create a (2D or 3D) map and estimate the position of the camera. But in my case this position is already known. So I am looking for a ROS SLAM package that can be supplied with accurate position data. Or a vision package that can be used to do stereovision with movement parallax.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66690/3d-vision-with-one-camera-/-vslam-with-known-position/) by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2573 on 2013-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

For SLAM using monouclar camera u can try ethzasl PTAM package. PTAM is well known monocular VSLAM algorithm. But as you might know that map created by monocular camera will created on an arbitrary scale.

For stereo vision you can use RGBD slam.

Hope this helps..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1